# How dynamically add columnSeries to Column chart in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

This is my full code. i'm trying to read sample xmllist and draw column series dynamically.Theoretically my code is correct but practically this is not working.guys can you help me to solve this.

```
private var testXML:XML=<main>
                                <data Country="USA" Gold1="10" Silver1="20" Bronze1="15"/>
                                <data Country="China" Gold="15" Silver="10" Bronze="25"/>
                            </main>;

protected function creationCompleteEvent(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        var List:XMLList=testXML.children();

        var attr:XMLList=List.attributes();

        column.dataProvider=List; ///data provider

        cat.categoryField=attr[List[0].attributes().length()].name();

        for(var j:Number=0 ; j<List.length() ; j++)
        {
            var currentSeries:Array = column.series; 

            var columnSeries:ColumnSeries=new ColumnSeries();

            for(var i:Number=0;i<List[j].attributes().length();i++)
            {
                //Alert.show(List[j].attributes()[i].name());

                //Alert.show(attr[List[j].attributes().length()].name());


                //Alert.show(List[j].attributes()[i]);

                columnSeries.dataProvider=List;

                columnSeries.xField=attr[List[j].attributes().length()].name();
                columnSeries.yField=List[j].attributes()[i];
                columnSeries.displayName=List[j].attributes()[i].name().toString();


                currentSeries.push(columnSeries); 
            }

            column.series = currentSeries;  
        }

    }
```

" column " is id of the column chart.

Comment: Did you tried using mxml.

Comment: Have you been able to create a chart with just a single series yet?